# Selenium Webdriver python storeTextPresent

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

How can I perform a storeTextPresent in Selenium WebDriver with python?

In Selenium IDE the following code works:

```
storeTextPresent regexp:[Tt]ext test
gotolf storedVars['test'] == true exists
```

Source:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeTextPresent</td>
    <td>regexp:[Tt]ext</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>storedVars['test'] == true</td>
    <td>exists</td>
</tr>
```

I want to do the same thing with Selenium WebDriver.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the solution!

```
self.assertRegex(driver.find_element_by_class_name("className").text,r"^[\s\S]*[Tt]ext*$")
```

This command tests that a regex search matches (or does not match) text. In case of failure, the error message will include the pattern and the text.

Best Regards.